# how to store table values from database in a 2d array in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a function in sql server which returns a table of n rows and m columns via JDBC in java. I want to store these values in a 2d array in java. How to determine the size and how to store the values. Can someone just give me a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use an ArrayList instead of an array, since you normally don't kn ow the size of the resultse -un less you do a count() in SQL first.

If you really need an array, cope the content after retrieving the records into an array.

Comment: lets assume that i will get the row count from database. Can you please tel me how do i proceed now?

Comment: Assuming tha values are Strings:String[][] array = new String[n][m];. And fill in the values while reading the records.

Comment: But how do i get the column count?

Comment: int m = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();   ?

Comment: AH - you can get ResultSetMetaData

Comment: ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

Comment: And please last question:

Comment: Assuming my bean name is HierarchyStruc, will the below code work?                                                
 HierarchyStruc[][] resultSet = new HierarchyStruc[rows][columns];
        int row = 0;
        while (result.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                resultSet[row][i] = result.getObject(i+1);
            }
            row++;
        }

Comment: Try to code it. Write a new question if you get sdtuck. There's tutorials on ythe web how to do it.